# Why doesn't WannaCry ask to "make changes to this computer" when you run the exe?

Tags: virus, ransomware

When you click on WannaCry, why doesn't it ask "do you want the following program to make changes to your computer?" I've watched videos of people running wannaCry, and it doesn't. I've also watched videos of people running meme virus, and it does ask If you allow the program to make changes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't exactly know what WannaCry does, but it wouldn't need permissions to change your personal files, only to change system files. You don't have to grant permission everytime you change a file with word. Its similar for WannaCry.